# I need to print if or else statments depending on user input, Once all input is correct I must print the users input under the button

Tags: javascript, html

So basically I am doing a project and I need to print the if/else statements under the button. 
I also need to print the Users input under the button when it is all correct.

Since I cant attach an image I will write the instructions here:

When the user clicks on the Register button a function is called to
validate and process the entered information. Write validation to:

User has entered a name. The minimum number of characters entered is
   two.

User has entered an address. The minimum number of characters
   entered is two.

e-mail addresses contain a ‘@’ symbol and at least
   one dot.

e-mail addresses have been entered and match. 
User has entered a Mobile and it is numeric 10 digits.
 Phone is optional, but if entered it must be numeric 10 digits. 
If the user does not provide the all the information, an appropriate error message should be
   displayed. 
The appropriate text box should be cleared, and focus placed on that page element. Sample error message:

I will attach my code as well... So at the moment when I enter the wrong text it will focus on the input box that I have got wrong aswell as show an alert.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function Validator() {
/*
Below will calculate to see if the right input has been put in, If the input is incorrect then it will give an alert and Focus on the text box that needs fixing. If the input is correct it will goto the next Input to see if it is correct!
After all inputs are verified they will be printed below.
*/


//Validate length of name input field       
enter code herevar ValidateName = document.getElementById('txtName').value;
var ValidateAddress = document.getElementById('txtAddress').value;
var ValidatePhone = document.getElementById('numPhone').value;
var ValidateMobile = document.getElementById('numMobile').value;
var confirmEmail = document.getElementById('txtconfirmEmail');  
var email = document.getElementById('txtEmail');
var filter =    /^([a-zA-Z0-9_.\-])+\@(([a-zA-Z0-9\-])+\.)+([a-zA-Z0-9]{2,4})+$/;

        if(ValidateName.length <= 2){
            alert("-ERROR- Please enter a name more than one letter!");
            document.getElementById('txtName').focus(); 

        }
        else {

            if(ValidateAddress.length <=2){
        alert("-ERROR- Please enter an address more than one letter");
            document.getElementById('txtAddress').focus();  

    }
        else{

            if (!filter.test(email.value)) {
        alert('Please provide a valid email address');  
            document.getElementById('txtEmail').focus();    

    }   
        else{
            if(txtEmail.value != txtconfirmEmail.value){
        alert('Please check your confirm email is correct');    
            document.getElementById('txtconfirmEmail').focus(); 

    }
        else{

        if(ValidatePhone.length != 10){
                alert("-ERROR- Please enter a phone number with exactly 10 numeric digits");
                document.getElementById(numPhone).focus();
        }
        else{
        if(ValidateMobile.length != 10){
            alert("-ERROR- Please enter a Mobile number with exactly 10 numeric digits");   
            document.getElementById('numMobile').focus();   
        }
        }

    }
    }



        }

        }










}
</script>
</head> 
<body> 

<div data-role="page" id="page">
    <div data-role="header">
        <h1>Kanye West</h1> <!--Name of artist -->
    </div>
    <div data-role="content" class="allPageBackground"> 
        <ul data-role="listview">
            <li><a href="#page2">Member Registration</a></li>
            <li><a href="#page3">Gala Ticket Order</a></li>
            <li><a href="#page4">Temperature Conversion</a></li>
            <!-- Above opens external albums.html page -->
        </ul>       
    </div>
    <div data-role="footer">
        <h4>James</h4>
    </div>
</div> <!-- End of NAVIGATION PAGE -->

<!--_________________________________________________-->

<!--Start of REGISTRATION PAGE(#page2)-->

<div data-role="page" id="page2" data-add-back-btn="true">
    <div data-role="header">
        <h1>Registration Page</h1>
    </div>
    <!--Start of forms-->
    <div data-role="content" class="allPageBackground">
    <p>Sign up and become a member to now!</p>
      <div data-role="fieldcontain">
        <label for="txtName">*Name:</label>
        <input type="text" name="txtName" id="txtName" value="" required  />
        <!--Everything is connected by "name"-->
      </div>

      <div data-role="fieldcontain">
        <label for="txtAddress">*Address</label>
        <input type="text" name="txtAddress" id="txtAddress" value="" required  />
      </div>

      <div data-role="fieldcontain">
        <label for="txtEmail">*e-Mail</label>
        <input type="email" name="txtEmail" id="txtEmail" value=""  />
      </div>

        <div data-role="fieldcontain">
        <label for="txtconfirmEmail">*Confirm e-Mail</label>
        <input type="email" name="txtconfirmEmail" id="txtconfirmEmail" value=""  />
       </div>

        <div data-role="fieldcontain">
        <label for="numPhone">Phone</label>
        <input type="number" name="numPhone" id="numPhone" value=""  />
        </div>

        <div data-role="fieldcontain">
        <label for="numMobile">*Mobile</label>
        <input type="number" name="numMobile" id="numMobile" value=""  />
        </div>

      </div>
            <p>* Required </p>
      <!--End of forms-->
      <!--Submit Button-->
      <button type="submit" value="Register" onClick="Validator()"></button>
      <label></label>
      <!--End of Submit BUtton-->      
    </div>
    <div data-role="footer">
        <h4>James</h4>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: is it possible for you to create a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/)?

Comment: Note: There is no form submit action done in your code

Comment: @thecbuilder Could I send you my file over email?

Answer (score 0):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function Validator() {
//Validate length of name input field       
var ValidateName = document.getElementById('txtName').value;
var ValidateAddress = document.getElementById('txtAddress').value;
var ValidatePhone = document.getElementById('numPhone').value;
var ValidateMobile = document.getElementById('numMobile').value;
var confirmEmail = document.getElementById('txtconfirmEmail');  
var email = document.getElementById('txtEmail');
var filter =    /^([a-zA-Z0-9_.\-])+\@(([a-zA-Z0-9\-])+\.)+([a-zA-Z0-9]{2,4})+$/;

    if(ValidateName.length <= 2){
        alert("-ERROR- Please enter a name more than one letter!");
        document.getElementById('txtName').focus(); 
        return false;
    } 
    if(ValidateAddress.length <=2){
        alert("-ERROR- Please enter an address more than one letter");
        document.getElementById('txtAddress').focus();  
        return false;
    }
    if (!filter.test(email.value)) {
        alert('Please provide a valid email address');  
        document.getElementById('txtEmail').focus();    
        return false;
    }   
    if(txtEmail.value != txtconfirmEmail.value){
        alert('Please check your confirm email is correct');    
        document.getElementById('txtconfirmEmail').focus(); 
        return false;
    }
    if(ValidatePhone.length != 10){
        alert("-ERROR- Please enter a phone number with exactly 10 numeric digits");
        document.getElementById(numPhone).focus();
        return false;
    }
    if(ValidateMobile.length != 10){
        alert("-ERROR- Please enter a Mobile number with exactly 10 numeric digits");   
        document.getElementById('numMobile').focus();   
        return false;
    }

 //add your document.frm.submit if you want
 return true;
}
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks, This is a better way to do it. Just wondering how to print the  comment in the alert alert as a String.

Comment: Inside Quotes the code consider as string, If you want to comment, do like this alert('something'); // error

Comment: Thanks but I don't understand what to do... I've had trouble with it for a while.

Comment: you want print comment statement in alert?

Comment: *you want to print  comment statement in alert?

Comment: Basically I want to print the same text in the alert. But I want to print that text underneath the button.. So:
<--Button-->
You have not entered a valid email
You have not entered a valid phone number

I want to do the same for the inputed text from the user when all the input fields are valid

Comment: then you can do instead of alert like this http://runnable.com/U_1qWGMtuIQBSPtm/output

Comment: Hi, that link did is not valid.

Answer (score 0):

I have found out how to print user input as well as using if statements to let them know they have entered the wrong data.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function Validator() {
//Validate length of name input field  
var errorMsg = "";     
var str = ""; 
var ValidateName = document.getElementById('txtName').value;
var ValidateAddress = document.getElementById('txtAddress').value;
var ValidatePhone = document.getElementById('numPhone').value;
var ValidateMobile = document.getElementById('numMobile').value;
var confirmEmail = document.getElementById('txtconfirmEmail');  
var email = document.getElementById('txtEmail');
var filter =  /*Email Symbol and letter Validator*/  /^([a-zA-Z0-9_.\-])+\@(([a-zA-Z0-9\-])+\.)+([a-zA-Z0-9]{2,4})+$/;
var regexPhone = /^\D*0(\D*\d){9}\D*$/; 
    /*alert(document.getElementById('txtName').innerHTML=txtName.value);
          alert(document.getElementById('txtName').innerHTML=txtName);
          */
    if(ValidateName.length <= 2){
            errorMsg += ("<b>-ERROR- Please enter a valid name with a length of at least 3 letters</b>");
            document.getElementById('errorMessage').innerHTML = errorMsg;
                    document.getElementById('txtName').focus();//this Focuses on textbox if input is wrong. 
                            //alert("-ERROR- Please enter a name more than one letter!"); 

        return false;
    } 
    if(ValidateAddress.length <=2){
            errorMsg += ("<b>-ERROR- Please enter a valid address with a length of at least 3 letters</b>");
            document.getElementById('errorMessage').innerHTML = errorMsg;
                    document.getElementById('txtAddress').focus();  //this Focuses on textbox if input is wrong.
                            //alert("-ERROR- Please enter an address more than one letter");

        return false;
    }
    if (!filter.test(email.value)) {
            errorMsg += ("<b>-ERROR- Please provide a valid email address.</b>");   
            document.getElementById('errorMessage').innerHTML = errorMsg;
                     document.getElementById('txtEmail').focus();//this Focuses on textbox if input is wrong.   
                            // alert('Please provide a valid email address');
        return false;
    }   
    if(txtEmail.value != txtconfirmEmail.value){
        errorMsg += ("<b>-ERROR- Please match up your email</b>");
        document.getElementById('errorMessage').innerHTML = errorMsg;
                document.getElementById('txtconfirmEmail').focus(); //this Focuses on textbox if input is wrong.
                        // alert('Please check your confirm email is correct');    

        return false;
    }
    if(ValidatePhone.length != 00){
        if(ValidatePhone.length != 10){
            errorMsg += ("<b>-ERROR- Please enter a phone number that is exactly 10 numeric digits</b>");
            document.getElementById('errorMessage').innerHTML = errorMsg;
                    document.getElementById('numPhone').focus();//this Focuses on textbox if input is wrong.
                        /*alert("-ERROR- Please enter a phone number with exactly 10 numeric digits");*/

            /*This error msg will not print if no numbers have been entered into the input box*/          
            return false;
        }
    }
    if(ValidateMobile.length != 10){
        errorMsg += ("<b>-ERROR- Please enter a Mobile number that is exactly 10 numeric digits</b>");
        document.getElementById('errorMessage').innerHTML = errorMsg;
                document.getElementById('numMobile').focus();//this Focuses on textbox if input is wrong.
                        /*alert("-ERROR- Please enter a mobile number with exactly 10 numeric digits");*/
        return false;
    }

else{
         str += ("thank You" + ValidateName + "<br>" + "Your address is: " + ValidateAddress +
        "<br>" + "Your phone is: " + ValidatePhone + "<br>" + "Your mobile is: " + ValidateMobile);
        document.getElementById('input').innerHTML = str;//This prints the users details.
        errorMsg = ("");
        document.getElementById('errorMessage').innerHTML = errorMsg; /*This will simply make errorMsg equal to nothing instead of the mobile error message.*/
}           
 return true;

}
</script>
```

Below here is my ALL INPUTS IN HERE Under your submit button all you need to do is make a

```
<p id="str"></p>

<p> id="errorMessage"</p>
```

Both errorMsg and Str variables will be printed inside. 
I used += to add the following statements.
I hope this helps any people in need.